# Cannot see all the details in a related list (Account Contact) in Lightning

Tags: lightning

When using Lightning we cannot see the same columns headers in the Account Contact related list. This appears fine in Classic but is missing details in Lightning.
We want to see the same in both but I can't figure out how to do this so any help is welcome. 
[image: Classic version]

[image: Lightning Version]